# React build favicons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть 10 фавиконок. Как мне их вставить в React так, чтобы они при вызове `npm run build` не перезаписывались дефолтным значением? И еще манифест обновялет.
Все, что я находил, это вручную менять каждый раз. Итого выходит, что кроме такого способа ничего нет? Нельзя нигде прописать в приложении, чтобы он этого не делалал или как-то заменить на свои?